# Can Ruby Koans be run on a mac?

Tags: ruby

I have ruby koans installed on a mac but when I enter

`$ ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb`

to start it, I get:

`bash: $: command not found`

Comment: Here's a link to a quick [introduction](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-the-command-line-2908368)

Answer (score 5):

Try entering `ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb` instead. With no `$`.

Comment: Yep! `$` is often used in examples to convey that the command is meant to be typed in at the command line, as compared to `irb` or what have you.